# What models can utilize multi-seasonal time-series using 'msts' class objects?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

'msts' is a class from the R forecast package developed by Rob Hyndman. I don't see an explicit list of models that can utilize multi seasonal time series in the help file or through searching SO. Does anyone know where I can find a list?

I understand that you can feed msts objects to any of the other models in the forecast package, but I specifically want to know which models will consider all seasonal patterns (for instance, ets/auto.arima will accept it, but will only consider one seasonal specification and ignore others).

Comment: I am aware of TBATS utilizing it, but not sure of any others.

Comment: Currently only bats() and tbats().